# How to prove the outer measure of a compact set in Rn is the infimum of sums of volumes of closed cubes?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, compactness

How to prove the outer measure of a compact set in Rn is the infimum of sums of volumes of a finite number of closed cubes? We defined outer measure using an infinite number of cubes, but I don't know why the outer measure of a compact set can be defined using a finite number of cubes....

Comment: What does it mean to be compact? How can you take advantage of your  collection of an infinite number of cubes to take advantage of compactness?

Comment: @user357980 I know there should be finite subcovers, but I don't know how to take advantage of it in this question.

Comment: Try to turn the infinite cover of closed cubes into an infinite cover of open cubes by changing the sum of the volumes by some $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @user357980 Should I turn closed cubes into open cubes, take a subcover and take the closure of every cube in it, then extend the lines of these cubes, get a finite number of new cubes and say we have a new cover of a finite number of closed cubes? And the outer measure of this new cover is less than the original outer measure by epsilon. Then we know inf should also be less than the original outer measure by epsilon.

Comment: You cannot just make the cubes smaller because it might not cover your compact set anymore.

Comment: @user357980 Should the proof be more straightforward? Can I say "find a finite subcover, take the closure of every open cube, and the measure of there union<= m(the compact set)+epsilon, thus inf m(union of finite closed cubes that covers the compact set)<=m(the compact set)"? Then to prove inf m(union of finite closed cubes that covers the compact set)>=m(the compact set) is easy. In the end we get inf m(union of finite closed cubes that covers the compact set)=m(the compact set). Does this make sense? Thanks~~

Comment: @user357980 I don't need to find a collection of a finite number of almost disjoint closed cubes, do I? The cubes in the subcover are not almost disjoint...